# Place div in specific column depending on screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-3 hidden-xs">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
    Column 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5 hidden-xs">
    Column 3
    <div id="important">This needs to be displayed</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there's an extra div in the third column. I'd like for it to be moved to the second column when the page is rendered in the `xs` size. I know I can just duplicate it but I'd rather not. Is there an easy/better way to accomplish this?

Edit: Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/FY98eVO6hC

Comment: Not the way you have it set up currently. But if you make the `important` div it's own column, you can use the [push/pull classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) to reorder them.

Comment: That sounds like a confusing UX. Perhaps if you explained the scenario a bit better we could help more.

Comment: @APAD1 Thanks but the push classes in Bootstrap don't specify a screen size so how would that work?

Comment: The push and pull classes in Bootstrap specify breakpoints the same way the columns do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get html of #important div and append if window load on small screen

```
function resize() {
    var docWidth = $(window).width();
    if (docWidth < 768){
        var getData = $('#important').html();
        $('.col-lg-3.hidden-xs #important').remove();
        $('.col-lg-3.hidden-xs').append('<div id="important">'+getData+'</div>');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    resize();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        resize(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess to keep it responsive I'd listen to window resize events.

Comment: I use "append" function if we run this on resize event it will continuously append that div, for that we first have to remove the older div then run append function.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just query the window width and act accordingly. The `xs` breakpoint is `767px`. You will obviously need to add additional logic to cater for the `#important` element needing to go back to column 3 when greater than `767px` though ;-)

js/jQuery

```
function resize()
{
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 767) // xs breakpoint
    {
        var html = $('#important').html(); // get the current "important" html
        $('#important').remove(); // remove from current column

        // Append to second/middle column
        $('.col-lg-4.hidden-xs').append('<div id="important">'+ html +'</div>');
    }
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
    resize(); // set on page load

    // listen for window resize events
    $( window ).resize(function() {
          resize(); 
    });
});
```

**NB**: Standard Bootstrap Breakpoints

```
xs = 0 - 767 pixels
sm = 768 - 991 pixels
md = 992 - 1199 pixels
lg = 1200+ pixels
```